# export to excel out of memory Exception and creating new worksheet if datagridview count greater than 64000

Tags: c#, winforms, out-of-memory, export-to-excel

I am using the below code to export to Excel. I have more than 100,000 records so I am creating new worksheet after each 64000 records. But my code always returning first 64000 records only. And giving me out of memory exception. How to over come this.

```
int rowcount = 0;
int sheetcount = 1;
int temprowcount = 0;
using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
{

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        rowcount++;
        if (rowcount == 64000)
        {
            DataTable tempdt = new DataTable();
            if (sheetcount == 1)
            {
                tempdt = dt.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Take(rowcount).CopyToDataTable();
            }
            if (sheetcount > 1)
            {
                temprowcount = temprowcount + rowcount;
                tempdt = dt.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().Skip(temprowcount).Take(rowcount).CopyToDataTable();
            }
            wb.Worksheets.Add(tempdt, comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + sheetcount.ToString());
            rowcount = 0;
            sheetcount++;
        }
    }
    wb.SaveAs(folderpath + "\\" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "_" + mydatetime.ToString("ddMMyyhhmmss") + ".xlsx");
}
```

Comment: I think you should dispose the `tempdt` after you have added it to excel. It would also be helpful if you showed the code for `CopyToDataTable`.

Comment: copy to datatable default linq function, i have updated the code

Comment: Ok, just as I thoght ;-) nevertheless, I'll tried to dispose it first and see if this is it.

Comment: I see you are never resetting `temprowcount` so it's bigger and bigger after each iteration... 64k, 128k, 192k, 256k,.... and you are using it to get this number of rows as a new `DataTable` this is probably too many.

Comment: because i have to skip the earlier rows and get next 64k rows so that i can add the new 64k rows to new worksheet. i am getting out of memory exception as i have more than 100,000 records

Comment: Oh, this is a `Skip`. My mistake ;-) then everthing's fine.

Comment: `wb.Worksheets.Add(tempdt, ..` seems to be a custom function. Can we see the code?

Comment: i am using closedxml

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a huge fan of all that Linq juggling if the problem to solve is straight forward. I've removed the need to do `Take` and `Skip` and only create one datatable to hold the 64,000 rows that are saved in the workbook.

You only got the first 64,000 rows because you forgot to anticipate for the fact that at the end of your main loop the DataTable could be only half filled but has not yet been written to your workbook.

```
int sheetcount = 1;
using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
{
    // copy over the Columns as XmlSchema
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    dt.WriteXmlSchema(ms);

    // read back the schema it the target 
    ms.Position = 0;
    DataTable tempdt = new DataTable();
    tempdt.ReadXmlSchema(ms);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {    
        tempdt.ImportRow(row);
        if (tempdt.Rows.Count == 64000)
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add(tempdt, String.Format("{0}{1}", comboBox1.SelectedItem,  sheetcount));
            sheetcount++;    
            tempdt.Clear(); // reset to zero rows
        }
    }
    // copy final/left over rows of the DataTable
    if (tempdt.Rows.Count > 0) 
    {
        wb.Worksheets.Add(tempdt, String.Format("{0}{1}", comboBox1.SelectedItem,  sheetcount));
        sheetcount++;    
    }
    tempdt.Dispose(); 
    wb.SaveAs(String.Format("{0}\\{1}_{2:ddMMyyhhmmss}.xslx",folderpath, comboBox1.SelectedItem, mydatetime));
}
```

I did try rather large sets with lot of columns but couldn't repro the Out of memory exception. You need to provide an exact stacktrace if you still run into that with this code and share a bit more of the characteristics of your DataTable.